# Does jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() insert rows in same order as given list?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a class of Employees

```java
public class Employee {
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

And a corresponding table in postgres with autogenerated PK.

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (
 id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR,
 employee_group INT
);
```

I want to use Springs `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` to insert many employees.

```java
List<Employee> employees = List.of(new Employee("Carlos"), new Employee("Jane"), ...);
String sql = "insert into employee (name, employee_group) values (?, ?)";
int batchSize = 100;

jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, employees, batchSize, (ps, employee) -> {
  ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
  ps.setInt(2, 1);
});
```

Assuming that this table is brand new, and that generated ids start from 1, does batchUpdate (or postgres?) guarantee that inserted rows will get keys following the order of the given list?
I.e, will the resulting table look like this?:

```
id | name  | employee_group
1    Carlos     1
2    Jane       1
...
```

The reason for my question is that I have a second table

```
CREATE TABLE employee_info (
 employee_id REFERENCES employee(id),
 phone VARCHAR
 ...
);
```

After I have batch-inserted the employees, I need to batch insert employee-info. For that I need the generated primary keys. If these are generated in the order of my list I know which ID belongs to which employee, by finding all ids with the given employee_group. Unfortunately jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate does not have a way of returning generated keys as far as I can find which would be the optimal solution.

Comment: Probably. But why do you care? Primary keys are supposed to be opaque unique identifiers with no "meaning". Attributing any meaning to the values is unwise.

Comment: The reason is that I need to make a second batchUpdate, to another table, that has a FK to the "employee"-table. 

CREATE TABLE employee_info (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT,
 employee_id INT REFERENCES employee(id),
 ...some more columns
);
`
If the ids are generated by the order of my list, I can easily figure out which PK belongs to which employee, and make the insert into the employee_info table.

Comment: But if the tables are empty and you're generating the IDs `BY DEFAULT` (and not `ALWAYS`), you could also assign them yourself?

Comment: @Kayaman I updated the question. The tables are not always empty but I will always have a unique employee_group that is distinct for that batch of employees. By querying "select id from employees where employee_group = ? order by id asc" I can get the IDs for that batch.

I could set the IDs myself but that would require me to get the max ID before the inserts, which in theory should be fine since its within a transaction but I would rather do it some other way if possible.

Comment: It sounds risky to presume what your id's are going to be. I think you would be better off (and safer) to update your `Employee` objects with the id set in the update and then insert your data into `employee_info`.

Comment: @hermit I added an extra column to the table with a unique id (UUID) that I generate in the java code before inserting the rows. After the insert is done, I can map the generated IDs to the created UUIDs in order to find what row corresponds to what object. It requires an extra column but solves the problem at least.